# c# winforms array items gets deleted

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I know this might look silly but I got a strange problem in my `winforms`. I have a windows application in which after a particular set of operations are completed I want to populate a **Checked ComboBox**. I am doing this using two classes. I want to **copy a array from helper class to the form class**. Array gets copied when `AddArrayItems` method is called. But when I see the ComboBox in the form, its null. After debugging with watch variables I got to know that the **problem** is after copying the array to Form1 array, as soon the control goes back to the caller, the array items are deleted. I tried to replicate my stuff, not exactly but still similar to what I am doing.

My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DemoApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
        string[] cboxAr;    

        public void AddCmboBoxItems(string[] cbArry)
        {
            cboxAr = new string[cbArry.Length];
            Array.Copy(cbArry, 0, cboxAr, 0, cbArry.Length); 
            //cbArry.CopyTo(cboxAr, 0);
            //foreach (string s in cboxAr)
                //comboBox1.Items.Add(s);
            comboBox1.Show();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HelperClass.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public class HelperClass
    {
        public HelperClass()
        {
        }

        public void HelperMethod()
        {
            SomeMethod();
        }

        private void SomeMethod()
        {
            string[] partnrName = new string[5] { "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5"};

            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.AddCmboBoxItems(partnrName);
        }

        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            new HelperClass().HelperMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what exactly the problem is here. Can anyone please push me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense.  Your `HelperClass` won't compile, you can't just put code like that outside of a method.  Nothing called your `HelperClass`.  And it never shows the form that it creates.  It looks like you've made a lot of changes to your actual code before posting it here, and those changes have made this code unusable.

Comment: It's because you don't understand OOP basics ... you are creating different instance of Form1

Comment: @David. yes. the code in `HelperClass` is within an method. I'm sorry I forgot while posting.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: Your code still doesn't compile.  And where do you ever call `somemethod()`?  Where do you ever `.Show()` the form it creates?  If you never show the form then the user will never see the controls on that form.

Comment: @David: I know my post doesn't have much code here. There are many fields in my HelperClass and I call somemethod() from one of the methods present in the class. Also somemethod() doesn't return anything.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: That's all well and good, but if you're asking us "what's wrong with this code" then the answer is that it doesn't compile and the compiler will tell you what the error is.  Once that's corrected, if you're asking us "why doesn't the user see the combo box options" then the answer is because you never show the form to the user.  You're creating a form, populating a control on that form, and then letting it fall out of scope without ever using it for anything.

Comment: @David: It compiles well and good. everything is fine, all the operations performed are successful. No warnings or errors. only this part of the code is not working properly. I just wanted to know why the array is nullified when the control is returned and how to fix it.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: *"everything is fine"* ... *"all the operations performed are successful"* ... This is not a realistic starting point when you're trying to solve a problem.  We can appreciate that you're trying to simplify what you're showing us, but in the process you are obscuring the actual problem by introducing a variety of other problems.  If we are going to identify the problem, we can't start from the assumption that "everything is fine".  See if you can replicate the problem with a minimal example.  Create a new separate program which does only this to demonstrate.

Comment: You create a new Instance of Form1 with the code: `Form1 f = new Form1();` If you want to add items in the combobox of the shown instance of Form1, then pass the instance to the method: `somemethod(Form1 f)`

Comment: @David: I tried to replicate my stuff. Please let me know if that helps. Coz even after testing this I get the same problem. I have created an array. In real time I'm getting data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never showing the form after modifying its controls:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.AddCmboBoxItems(partnrName);
```

But you're calling this from within an *existing* form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelperClass.DoSomething();
}
```

Presumably you want to modify the controls on *that* form?  Then you'll need a reference to that form.  Pass one to the method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelperClass.DoSomething(this);
}
```

And accept it in the method definition:

```
public static void DoSomething(Form1 form)
{
    new HelperClass().HelperMethod(form);
}
```

And so until the point where you need to use it.  (Side note: You have *a lot* of weird indirection happening here with a seemingly random mix of static and instance methods and classes.  You can simplify a lot, which will make this involve fewer code changes.)

Ultimately, `SomeMethod` needs the instance of the form to modify:

```
private void SomeMethod(Form1 form)
{
    string[] partnrName = new string[5] { "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5"};

     form.AddCmboBoxItems(partnrName);
}
```

To illustrate the overall point, consider an analogy...

A car rolls off of an assembly line.  You open the trunk and put a suitcase inside.  Moments later another car rolls off of the same assembly line.  It is identical to the first car in every way.  When you open the trunk of the second car, do you expect to find your suitcase inside it?

A `Form` is an object like any other.  Changes made to one instance of an object are not reflected in other instances of the same object.  Each instance maintains its own state.  In order to modify a particular instance, you need a reference to that instance.

Comment: Yes that work's just perfect. Thank you so much. And sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava: Glad we could help!  Debugging is an interesting but important thing to learn.  There *a lot* of value in create an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Not just for us to help you here, but for your own ability to understand the problems.  Good luck!

Comment: I truly understand that. And I would take it as a positive suggestion and try my best. Thank you again.